# Use field generated within $group in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo query that does something like this:

```
$group: {
  _id: { ....},
  foo: {
    $push: {
       field1: { $map: { input: "myObjects", as: "obj", in: "$$obj.title" }
       field2: myArray
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to concatenate field1 with myArray to generate field2. I tried doing this:

`field2: { $concatArrays: ["$field1", myArray] }`

But I only get the value from myArray.

Comment: You mean you tried to do it in the same `$group` statement? That is because `$field1` does not exist at that point. Instead do `$push: { "combined": { "$concatArrays": [myArray, { "$map": { "input": "$myObjects", "in": "$$this.title" } }] } }`. That corrects **one** issue, but I'm not entirely convinced that is what you want. It's not clear in your question if `myArray` is your own variable or a field in the document, same for `myObjects` for that matter ( I presumed a "field", hence `"$myObjects"` ). You could make this clearer by showing a small data sample and what you expect.

Comment: Also the result of `$push` here when supplying arrays is just going to be an "array of objects with a single property which contains an array". So again, not convinced that is what you want. Showing examples makes it clear to everyone what you expect.

Comment: Your suggestion worked well! Thanks, Neil! Please put that as an answer so I can accept